# how to implement CRC alogirthm to check the data intergrity in .net wcf application

Tags: wcf, hex, crc32

I am just trying to implement 32-bit CRC Algorithm with initial seed of 0x0  to check a xml string integrity in .net wcf application.

i am returning a Xml string.and the fixed-length
hexadecimal string generated from the value of the CRC .  how can i implement CRC alogirthm for a xml string and convert CRC to hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 0):

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) provides a `crc32()` function for this purpose.  A little bit of googling will turn up many other implementations in source code.